# Put facebook avatar url into img[src] doesn't work in Ionic 3

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

In sample, have two avatar URLs, one of them doesn't show up in ionic app and just do download in browser, instead to open in tab.

So if put this url that doesn't work(1) into [src] attribute, image is not loaded in ionic emulator and in real device, but everything is OK in Chrome.

1. https://graph.facebook.com/105656846898488/picture?width=200&height=200&redirect=false&type=normal
2. https://graph.facebook.com/67563683055/picture?width=200&height=200&redirect=false&type=normal

ex. of usage:

```
<img [src]="user.avatar">
```

Parse method:

```
let x = new XMLHttpRequest();
  x.open("GET", `https://graph.facebook.com/${facebookUserId}/picture?width=200&height=200&redirect=false`, false);
  x.send(null);
  return JSON.parse(x.responseText).data.url;
```

I guess something with facebook server setting, because both images pulled from different server domains.

Image with facebook userid: 67563683055 - work's good.

Comment: +1 ...Same problem here ...  with a "large" userId for ex. 18803313xxxxxxxx image is not OK but tested with userID mentionned above 67563683055 it's working. ...

Comment: Maybe related to this ... https://stackoverflow.com/a/49519880/1426729

Comment: Can not reproduce this problem anymore  maybe it's fixed ...

Comment: Yes, i can confirm, issue is gone for me also, seems like bug was on FB server side.